# How can I redirect a single segment url without forward slash at the end?

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, crash

My website's htaccess file is not allowing a single segment's redirect without a forward slash at the end. If I leave it off, it loops and crashes the website. How can I allow my users to go to [site].com/winter-camping and have it be redirected? This is what I have set up that currently works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch permanent /find-a-park/ https://[site].com/about/find-a-park
RedirectMatch permanent /winter-camping/ https://[site].com/about/promotion-details/winter-camping

#our rules:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically I don't want my users to *have* to put the forward slash at the end to get to the page at all.

I do have instances that do work, however, which is why I'm confused. The only difference is they're subpages:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /parks/about/central-park https://[site].com/parks/central-park
```

One thing to know is that we use ExpressionEngine as our CMS. How can I get those first two redirects to redirect their urls and not crash my site? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only `mod_rewrite` rule and use a regex with optional trailing slash:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^find-a-park/?$ https://[site].com/about/find-a-park [L,NC,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^winter-camping/?$ https://[site].com/about/promotion-details/winter-camping [L,NC,R=301]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```